# problemas con series de tiempo en pandas

Tags: pandas

Tengo un archivo csv con una serie de tiempo (la mayoría de días no son consecutivos como se puede ver). Hago:

```
from pandas import read_csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
llueve = read_csv('H:/lluvia.csv', header=0, parse_dates=True, squeeze=True)
```

Mis datos son como estos

```
> Fecha Total
0   12/02/2015  5422016
1   17/02/2015  5314348
2   06/03/2015  5514032
3   10/03/2015  5243431
4   15/03/2015  2770089
... ... ...
750 28/09/2019  4684501
751 28/09/2019  4684501
752 29/09/2019  4476017
753 30/09/2019  4757711
754 30/09/2019  4757711
```

Aparentemente python tomaba las fechas como strings, por lo cual hice :

```
llueve['Fecha']= pd.to_datetime(llueve['Fecha'], dayfirst=True)
```

sin embargo, al querer correr:

```
 %matplotlib inline
 llueve.plot(kind='bar');
```

marca el error:

> ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

no entiendo cuál es el problema. Sé poco acerca de python, así que agradecería respuestas sencillas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `pandas.plot()` usa por defecto para el eje X el índice del dataframe, que en tu caso es una serie numérica 0, 1, 2... en vez de una fecha.

Tienes dos soluciones:

1. Decirle a `pandas.plot()` qué columna quieres usar para el eje x, con la siguiente sintaxis:

   ```
   llueve.plot(x="Fecha", kind="bar")
   ```

   [image: Resultado]
2. Convertir la columna "Fecha" en indice

   ```
   llueve = llueve.set_index("Fecha")
   ```

   Tras esto el dataframe ahora se vería así:

   ```
                 Total
   Fecha              
   2015-02-12  5422016
   2015-02-17  5314348
   2015-03-06  5514032
   2015-03-10  5243431
   2015-03-15  2770089
   2019-09-28  4684501
   2019-09-28  4684501
   2019-09-29  4476017
   2019-09-30  4757711
   2019-09-30  4757711
   ```

   y ya puedes hacer directamente `llueve.plot(kind="bar")` (lo que daría una figura idéntica a la antes mostrada).

   Además, teniendo las fechas en el índice, puedes hacer otras cosas, como resamplear por meses, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pareció funcionar sin problemas. Pero ahora quiero resamplear (usando goupby) por meses y/o años y no puedo. Intento lo siguiente:    ``llueve.set_index('Fecha').resample('M')["Total"] `` y obtengo: KeyError: "None of ['Fecha'] are in the columns" ¿dónde está el error?